# Composer error with GitHub OAuth token on fresh laravel/homestead provision

Tags: github, laravel-5, composer-php, homestead

Fresh installed a `laravel/homestead` vagrant box, as per docs, run the `init.sh`, configured `Homestead.yaml` and ran `$ vagrant up; vagrant ssh`. Afterwards `cd`'ed to project's folder and ran `composer install`.

It hangs waiting for a `token` with the following message

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
- Installing sebastian/diff (1.3.0)
Downloading: Connecting...
Could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/sebastianbergmann/diff/zipball/863df9687835c62aa423a22412d26fa2ebde3fd3, please create a GitHub OAuth token to go over the API rate limit
Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+homestead+2015-08-01+2140
to retrieve a token. It will be stored in "/home/vagrant/.composer/auth.json" for future use by Composer.
Token (hidden):
```

I have used `laravel/homestead` before, and I have never had to do any of these, is this some *undocumented* new feature or a bug or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You'll need to create a GitHub account if you don't already have one and then follow the instruction [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/) and then copy the token.

Once you've got your token, run composer install again and then paste the token in when it prompts you for it.

Comment: Well this solved it. I'm just confused about why did it suddenly asked for a token; like, I've been using Laravel for a year now, never got asked for a Token.

Comment: how to run composer install again in command line in windows?

Comment: The reason you suddenly have to do this even though you have never had to do so before is that you have gone over the Github API rate limit, which is currently 60 requests per hour.

Answer (score 6):

The error means that you have exceeded the API rate limit for your IP address.

You can either:

- wait a bit and re-try again,
- change your IP address (e.g. by connecting via proxy or VPN),
- specify your authentication token as suggested by the message:

  > Please create a GitHub OAuth token to go over the API rate limit
  >   Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo

  and pass into your Composer command or add it manually into `~/.composer/auth.json`, e.g.

  ```
  {
      "http-basic": {},
      "github-oauth": {
          "github.com": "__TOKEN__"}
  }
  ```

  <sup>Note: On Windows, it's in [`%APPDATA%/Composer`](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2366#issuecomment-64175023).</sup>

  or add the settings manually by the following commands (as per this [comment](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3609#issuecomment-69243103)):

  ```
  composer config -g --unset github-oauth.api.github.com
  composer config -g github-oauth.github.com __TOKEN__
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Go into your github account: https://github.com/settings/tokens/new
then generate a new token copy then add it into your the terminal like that

```
composer config --global --auth github-oauth.github.com your_token_here
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings then Developer settings from personal access token you can generate a new token

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness' sake:

I had an expired token sitting in my Composer `auth.json` file, which resulted in me getting prompted for a new token despite not hitting the Github API limit.

In my case, I simply had to `nano ~/.composer/auth.json` and drop my old tokens from the `github-oauth` section. I also deleted all of my expired Github tokens as well, just to make sure.

Once I cleared out the cruft, everything began functioning as expected for me.

If one indeed has hit the API limit, then there's no way around it and my answer probably won't help. But it might be worth checking into first before creating a whole new token.