# Composer.phar install issue

Tags: php, paypal, composer-php, token, phar

I've trying to install composer however I can't understand this line, what do i need to do? I've try going to the github tokens settings but which token do I actually need to generate? Does anyone encounter issue similar to this when installing?

```
    php composer.phar install
```

Could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/paypal/sdk-core-php/zipball/9826992e67c2fdac3999c8e29bb71f423f64c2a2, please create a GitHub OAuth token to go over the API rate limit
Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+ip-172-31-8-231+2015-10-05+0250
to retrieve a token. It will be stored in "/home/ubuntu/.composer/auth.json" for future use by Composer.

Comment: http://www.techycommerce.com/composer-in-paypal-sdk-failure/

Comment: Same thing occurs, any idea?
`Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing behat/gherkin (v4.4.0)
    Downloading: Connecting...
Could not fetch https://api.github.com/repos/Behat/Gherkin/zipball/6b3f8cf3560dc4909c4cddd4f1af3e1f6e9d80af, please create a GitHub OAuth token to go over the API rate limit
Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+ip-172-31-8-231+2015-10-05+0322
to retrieve a token. It will be stored in "/home/ubuntu/.composer/auth.json" for future use by Composer.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer error with GitHub OAuth token on fresh laravel/homestead provision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766546/composer-error-with-github-oauth-token-on-fresh-laravel-homestead-provision)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error says, go to the github link provied and create a token.  Then copy the token and run:

`php composer config --global github-oauth.github.com <TOKEN>`

Replace  with the token github provides you.

Comment: thanks i manage to install with the token, but how do u actually know which to select? I basically selected everything & generate token, not sure if i have done it correctly

Comment: You should be fine with just the defaults

Answer (score 1):

The other workaround for this would be to use `php composer.phar install --prefer-source`

This will download the source. Just another alternative.